# Ajax ignoring URL

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I try to make an ajax request through JQuery triggering an onClick event, but when it sends the AJAX request I receive:

> **PATCH http://localhost:8000/courses 405 (Method Not Allowed)** (Current page) Because it doesn't get the URL with the id

**HTML**

```
@foreach ($courses as $course)
    <tr>
      <td>{{ Form::select('year', $years, ['class' => 'form-control'], [ 'placeholder' => $course->academicYear]) }}</td>
      <td>{{ Form::select('subject', $subjects, ['class' => 'form-control'], [ 'placeholder' => $course->subject]) }}</td>
      <td>
        <a href="" id="saveCourse" class="btn btn-success pull-left">Save</a>
        <input type="hidden" id="idCourse" value="{{ $course->id }}">
      (...)
```

**JQUERY + AJAX**

```
$('#saveCourse').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var id = $('#idCourse').val();

        // Ignore this logic
        var values = {year: "", subject:"", id: id};
        var parameters = ['year', 'subject'];
        var i = 0;
        $('td > select option:selected').each(function() {
            values[parameters[i]] = $(this).text();
            i++;
        });

        // Ajax request
        $.ajax({
            type: 'patch',

            // Appending the course id here not working, 
            // but if i put anything else like /blabla/ + id ajax doesn't ignore it...

            url:  '/courses/' + id,
            headers: {'X-CSRF-Token': csrf_token},
            dataType: 'json',
            data: values,

            success: function (response) {
                console.log("SUCCESS: " + response);
            },
            error: function (reject) {
                if( reject.status === 422 ) {
                    $("#error").text("Los datos dados no cumplen el formato requerido.");
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

**WEB.PHP**

```
/* -----COURSE_ROUTES------ */
    Route::resource('courses', 'CourseController')->except([
        'create', 'edit'
    ]);
```

**ROUTES**
[image: Routes]

**EDIT**

If I use `POST` instead of `PATCH` in `type` AJAX gets the id.

Found a GitHub issue with the same problem https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/3944

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220142/discussion-on-question-by-repikas-ajax-ignoring-url).

Comment: @DigitalDrifter If i log that `.val()` i get the correct index so the url is ok, i can see it logging but `AJAX` somehow is changing the URL dynamically. I have a very similar code doing the same thing and it is working, i have compared both files and they're almost the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to put this condition at the start of the update method in the controller... Now it works!

```
if(request()->ajax()) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

PUT and PATCH are request methods. An HTTP error of 405, which you get means that the server knows the request method, but the service does not support it. Read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/405

Comment: I already know that, the problem here is AJAX ignoring the id in the URL when i use PUT/PATCH

Comment: @Repikas PUT/PATCH is ignored by the server as a whole, this is what the error is telling you. Since the whole request is ignored in the case of PUT/PATCH, the id is ignored as well. If a girl ignores your bucket of flowers, then she ignores all individual files inside that bucket, if that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

not sure if matters but try PATCH instead of patch

```
type: 'PATCH',
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned below the `405` **(METHOD NOT ALLOWED)** basically means you're ajax request method `PATCH` is not allowed for the specific resource on the server.

If you using a routing library you can go their docs and search how to change this behavior. A route can accept one or multiple request methods, I assume that the `Route::resource` create a route with method `POST` by default, which explains that the ajax request works in POST type.

Comment: I know how this error works, and i have the PUT/PATCH route with `resource` since i have the `update` route, you can see it in the image. That's the problem, it is not that simple